# Redirection authentication form in PHP when preventDefault is used

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a authentication form in a html page and use PHP to check if the users/password are correct.
I call my php script with jquery ajax and use the preventDefautlt to avoid reload page effect.

What I want to do is : if user/password are correct redirect the user to the authorized page if not display en error message.
My question is, do I need to redirect the user from my php script with Header function or from javascript when the user/password are ok ?
Is safe to redirect form js?

```
$( "#signin" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this ), url = $form.attr( "action" );
    console.log($form.serialize() );
    var posting = $.post( url, $form.serialize() );
    posting.done(function( data ) {
        if(data =="LOGGED-IN"){
            //make the redirection;
        }else if(data =="USER-PASSWORD-KO"){
            //display error message
        }
        console.log(data); 
        //$( "#login-dialog" ).append( data );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with javascript like,

```
posting.done(function( data ) {
   if(data =="LOGGED-IN"){
      window.location.href='home.php';//let you want to redirect it on home.php
   }else if(data =="USER-PASSWORD-KO"){
      alert('Invalid Username/password')
   }
   console.log(data); 
   //$( "#login-dialog" ).append( data );
});
```

And if you are sending username and password using `js` then there is no matter of safe for redirection.

Comment: this doesn't work as I use `event.preventDefault()`. Why you said there is no matter of safe when send password in POST with JS?

Comment: @skunka `event.preventDefault` would prevent the submission of the form, it will not prevent to redirect(by using location.href) the page.